# Битрикс - переход сайта с http на https

Tags: битрикс, http, https

При переходе сайта с http на https протокол, обнаружилась проблема в адресной строке в карточке товара пишет:"Не защищено".
При чем на остальных страницах - все нормально...
Прописал в robots.txt - Хост с https и установил редирект с http на http в .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://мой сайт.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Кто может подсказать в чем проблема и где копать?
Вот полное содержание файла:

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://мой сайт.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
    php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

    #php_value display_errors 1

    #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: ssl установлен корректно? https://www.leaderssl.ru/tools/ssl_checker проверьте

Comment: Результат проверки:   Сертификат проверен и установлен правильно
                                                                                                                    Срок действия SSL сетрификата закончится менее чем через 90 дней. 
 Сервер поддерживает устаревший (менее безопасный) протокол SSL v2. Настоятельно рекомендуем отключить его

Comment: правила  Rewrite работают так: чем ниже тем больше приоритет, возможно у вас ниже редирект на http.Так же проверьте правильность правила , название домена и т д

Comment: добавьте код внутрь <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Comment: когда добавлял во внутрь <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> - сайт вообще не отвечал ни по http ни по https

Comment: нужно добавить после строки RewriteEngine On, либо в конце

Comment: еще как вариант на хостинге настроен редирект, и вы настроили редирект в .htaccess, поэтому он редиректит очень много, из за этого возникает ошибка слишком частого редиректа от сервера

Comment: А как определить, что именно не правильно настроено? На хостинге стоит Битрикс-Виртуальная машина...

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/messages/forum32/topic80203/message413441/#message413441

Comment: инструкция для vm https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=37&LESSON_ID=8855&LESSON_PATH=3908.8809.8847.8855